# What is the link between normal acceleration and radius of curvature?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, curvature

hope you are well,
So , in my physics class we use graphical method to determine the radius of curvature and as we know this method isn't very accurate, so when I watch a YouTube video I find this relation:

[image]

So is this relation always true? Because I was able to find it before watching the video, but with the condition of $ay=0$.

Comment: Yes. You can derive it if you know the mathematics here.

Comment: I would consider this to be the *definition* of the radius of curvature of a curve $\vec{r}(t)$. So it must always be true by definition.